# how do I get the file content from a form?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the contents of a file form a HTML form?  Here is an example of what I'm working with.  All it does it output something like "C:\Fake Path\nameoffile

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething(){
        var fileContents = document.getElementById('idexample').value;
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = fileContents;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body >

<form name = "form_input" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="whocares" id="idexample" />
<button type="button" onclick="doSomething()">Enter</button>

</form>

<div id="outputDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
It seems the solution is difficult to implement this way.  What I'm trying to accomplish is sending a file to a python script on my webserver.  This is my first time trying this sort of thing so suggestions are welcome.  I supposes I could put the python script in my cgi folder and pass the values to it using something like...

```
/cgi/pythonscript.py?FILE_OBJECT=fileobjecthere&OTHER_VARIABLES=whatever
```

Would this be a better solution for sending file content to a webserver rather than having javacript  open it directly using FileReader?

Comment: You *may* be able to do that with the [HTML5 File Api](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) (on browsers that support it).

Comment: Ah, I wish I'd googled this a little before I posted.  Apparently this is not possible with javascript.  It seems it can be done in IE using ActiveX (or so I've read).  Looks like I'll need another solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can actually do that with the new `FileReader` Object.

Try this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vDdFy/)

```
function doSomething()
{
    var file = document.getElementById('idexample');

    if(file.files.length)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = e.target.result;
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);
    }
}
```

(works with the newest versions of Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: That worked in Firefox but not in Chrome, still trying to figure out why.  You mentioned that FileReader is new.  So this would not work for older browsers?

Comment: This API is quite new. It should work in Chrome 7+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 10 and Opera 11.10+ according to [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Can't get it to work in anything but Firefox.  I was about to give the correct answer to Neil since your solution doesn't work all in all instances but I'll give you the correct answer since you did provide an interesting example ( sorry Neil :( )

Comment: how can I upload the file into online servers (e.g. AWS S3) using this code? shall I send the `e.target.result` ?

Answer (score 0):

yes. Replace line of input as given below, Then it will work :)

```
<input type="file" ACCEPT="text/html" name="whocares" id="idexample" />
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  I am using Chrome though.  I don't have IE.  Is this solution browser specific?  I need one that will work on all browsers

Answer (score -4):

You **cannot** get the contents of a file in a form without submitting the form to your server.

Comment: Ah.  Okay it looks like I'll need another solution.

Comment: @bitnuk3r that is what it seems ^_^

Comment: because you actually can, probably, so your answer is wrong

Comment: Use FileReader API