# Android webscrape - How to download a file from a site when the site uses a javascript download function

Tags: android, web-scraping, download, jsoup

I am using Jsoup in my app to scrape data from a site. Everything was fine until I came across the 'download' part of the app. It would be easy if the download link is in the href value but this site uses a javascript function

Here's how the site is layed out:

This is the link to the file:

`<a href="javascript:download(11848,'d915f46123');">Ai Ai Ai ni Utarete Bye Bye Bye</a>`

Below is the javascript download function. It accepts a songid and a key, builds a string with the passed arguments and sets it as the form's action attribute, and calls the form's submit method:

`function download(songId, key) 
{

var form = document.getElementById('dlForm');       form.action = '/download/zephzeph/' + key + '/' + songId + '.mp3';

form.submit();

}`

Below is the form:

`<form id="dlForm" action="/amusic/download.php" method="POST"></form>`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly, do elaborate, if not.

I would try to right click on the download link and open it in a new tab. The new link is what you need to emulate in your scraper.

My experience with net scraping is very limited, but I would be more than happy to help you find a solution. :)

Comment: Yeap. Already tried that but it only gives me the function call not the link: `javascript:download(11848,'d915f46123');`

Comment: Could you share the website in question? I will try to hack something together.

Comment: sure. Though you need to create an account in order to generate the href value or else it will just generate a link to login/register page. The site is gendou.com/amusic/

Comment: btw the you can download the file by clicking the name of the song

Comment: It's hard for me to get the context of your last comment.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. You know how the data is presented in a table? You need to click on the name of the song under the 'Song(Link)' column to download it.

Comment: Could you try this answer, please? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8645576/2796939

I used to use XMLHttpRequest for image scraping, maybe the same methodology can be applied to your problem as well? Especially since the link to the php script is exposed.

Comment: not quite sure with the posted thread. Though i found a similar scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621778/htmlunit-to-invoke-javascript-from-href-to-download-a-file.             Bu I am wondering how to implement this in android. It uses HtmlUnit third party library

Comment: I, personally, am not a big proponent of third party libraries, especially in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way I can achieve this is to use a webview. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html?m=1. I'll try and see if it will work.