# Getting the value of type-file input

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using multer to upload a file (mostly to store images) and I prevented the default of the form on submit to do some front-end stuff and make a payload object and send it via ajax, I realized that I can't get the value or file of the type-file input unlike the normal form which is `form.value` and because of all that the `req,file` on multer returns undefined.

I expected a property of the payload that is defined on the `req.file`

```
form.on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      const url = this.action;
      const method = form.attr('methodData').toUpperCase();

      const elements = this.elements;
      const payload = {};

      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].type != 'submit' && elements[i].name.length > 0) {
          payload[elements[i].name] = elements[i].value;
        }
      }

      // if there's an input type file with the name of 'img', the img value will be the name of the chosen file instead of the file data
});
```

Is there a way to get the value or file of the type-file input (not the `/fakepath/` one)

Comment: Try using `FormData`

Comment: how can I get the file data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645369/how-do-i-get-the-file-content-from-a-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I get the file content from a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645369/how-do-i-get-the-file-content-from-a-form)

Comment: it seems like using the `FileReader` is not working for me, it returns undefined.